# query to fetch multiple row data in Columns format - postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, left-join, self-join

I have table structure like this: Table - contact_details

```
role                email        userId
Primary Contact    a1@b.com        1
Secondary Contact  b1@b.com        1
End User           c1@b.com        1

Primary Contact    a2@b.com        2
Secondary Contact  b2@b.com        2
```

Result data should be:

```
Primary Contact       Secondary Contact    End User      UserId
a1@b.com                  b1@b.com          c1@b.com       1
a2@b.com                  b2@b.com          null           2
```

I am not able to retrieve End User as "null" for userId -2, what is happening is either the entire row comes if data exists for all three roles OR if any role is missing entire row missed.

Can any one suggest the approach please?

-- Postgres version - 12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this (conditional aggregation)

```
select
  max(case when role = 'Primary Contact' then email else null end) as PrimaryContact,
  max(case when role = 'Secondary Contact' then email else null end) as SecondaryContact,
  max(case when role = 'End User' then email else null end) as EndUser,
  userId    
from contact_details
group by userId
```

Comment: Excellent! Appreciate your knowledge. It did my work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to help @AbhishekSingh